# System.IndexOutOfRangeException in my Nearest Point Calculation Program

Tags: c#

I received System.IndexOutOfRangeException in the part of the SearchForTheNextDotsTopRight() method

```
if ((pointsArray[i].X == j) &&
                   ((pointsArray[i].Y) <= p.Y))
```

I just simply don't know why the array is not functioning in this situation. Looking forward for help, thanks you a lot!

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Draw_Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static int sizeOfArray = 20;
        int TopBorderY = 100;
        int LeftBorderX = 100;
        int BottomBorderY = 800; 
        int RightBorderX = 800;
    
    Point Base = new Point(0, 0);
    Point[] pointsArray = new Point[sizeOfArray];

    public Form1()
    {   
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void PointsArray(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
        {
            pointsArray[i].X = rand.Next(100, 800);
            pointsArray[i].Y = rand.Next(100, 800);
            CreateDots(pointsArray[i], e);
        }
        Point Nearest = SearchForTheFirstDots(pointsArray);
        CreateLines(Base, Nearest, e);
        Point Next = SearchForTheNextDotsTopRight(Nearest, pointsArray);
        CreateLines(Nearest, Next, e);
    }

    private Point SearchForTheNextDotsTopRight(Point p, Point[] pointsArray)
    {
        Point PointNext = p;
        for (int j = p.X; j <= RightBorderX; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= sizeOfArray; i++)
            {
                if ((pointsArray[i].X == j) &&
                   ((pointsArray[i].Y) <= p.Y))
                {
                    PointNext = pointsArray[i];
                    goto endofLoop:
                }
            }
        }
        endofLoop:
        return PointNext;    
    }

    private double CalculateDistance(Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        double distance = Math.Pow(p1.X - p2.X, 2) + Math.Pow(p1.Y - p2.Y, 2);
        return distance;
    }

    private Point SearchForTheFirstDots(Point[] pointsArray)
    {
        Point Nearest = pointsArray[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
        {
            if (CalculateDistance(Base, pointsArray[i]) < 
                CalculateDistance(Base, Nearest))
            {
                Nearest = pointsArray[i];
            }
        }
        //pointList.Add(Nearest);
        return Nearest;
    }

    private void CreateDots(Point p, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 3);
        int width = 3;
        int height = 3;
        int pointXform = p.X - width / 2;
        int pointYform = p.Y - height / 2;
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(pointXform, pointYform, width, height);
        g.DrawEllipse(pen, r);
    }

    private void CreateLines(Point p1, Point p2, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 3);
        g.DrawLine(pen, p1, p2);
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        Point p1 = new Point(25, 25);
        Point p2 = new Point(100, 150);
        
        PointsArray(e);
    }


}
```

}

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i <= sizeOfArray; i++) ` i == sizeOfArray will lead to `pointsArray[i]` throwing OutOfBounds because arrays are indexed 0-based. That means indices go from 0 to Length-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace:

```
        for (int i = 0; i <= sizeOfArray; i++) //<---------------
        {
            if ((pointsArray[i].X == j) &&
               ((pointsArray[i].Y) <= p.Y))
            {
                PointNext = pointsArray[i];
                goto endofLoop:
            }
        }
```

by

```
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++) //<---------------
        {
            if ((pointsArray[i].X == j) &&
               ((pointsArray[i].Y) <= p.Y))
            {
                PointNext = pointsArray[i];
                goto endofLoop:
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I recognize my dumbness in this very small part.

Comment: no problem , to close the question, dont forget to validate and upvote the ansver..